# Start Process From Parent Function in Python

Tags: python, parent-child, python-multiprocessing

I wanted to know if my Process has stopped working from my function which started this Process

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def parent_function():
    i = 0
    while True:
        #some code processing
        if i == 0: #start this process only first time
           temp = Process(target=process_function)
           temp.start()

def process_function():
    While True:
        #some code waiting or processing
```

If some exception occurs in `process_function()` my `parent_function` doesn't know about it. How to restart that process function again from `parent_function()` and keep checking if `process_function()` is running or not.

Comment: Are you calling parent_function multiple times, to start multiple processes?

Comment: No, parent_function is called once but there is an indefinite loop running in parent function. So as long as this loop is running I want the process function to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_alive()` method to check whether the child process terminated. It returns `True` or `False`. It could be something like this in your `parent_function()`:

```
if not temp.is_alive():
    # restart the process
```

Comment: Actually I did it same way earlier. Anyway Thanks for answer.